# How to link 5 apps from one app. New to android

Tags: android

I have 5 android apps and im trying to make a front page that has 5 buttons that connects to each one. How do I go about this? i tried to create a onclick method in layout but it didnt work.

Comment: just add google play link of your other games..

Answer (score 0):

you can use the package name of App to open them on button click as :

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: Just to clarify. I put this in MainActivity? then on layout of the button I go onClick:"com.package.address"); ?

Comment: no, its not like that. Its code to call an activity of another app.

Comment: so that you can launch 5 app from 5 buttons of your app layout.

Comment: well im sort of using an android virtual device im trying to make it work before i test it on a real device. i put all 5 apps in one folder and i have a 6th folder for the frontpage.

Comment: what do you mean by "i put all 5 apps in one folder and i have a 6th folder for the frontpage"? did you install the app in your avd or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                  
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your Package name"));
startActivity(i);
```

Declare it in your Activity.

Let me know if it helps you.